# How set ntpd log to DEBUG or something more verbose

Tags: server, ntp

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 and configured time synchronization with my Windows Domain controller through `ntpd`.
My config file, `/etc/ntp.conf`, contains:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntpd.log
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
server 1.2.5.6 iburst burst minpoll 6 maxpoll 8
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

ntpd starts and I think it works fine.  Here's an example `ntpq -pn` command output:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*1.2.5.6     1.2.5.3      4 u   53   64    3    0.591    3.830   8.130
```

But in the log file `/var/log/ntpd.log`, I have only this:

```
 3 Mar 14:26:05 ntpd[8457]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
 3 Mar 14:26:05 ntpd[8457]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
 3 Mar 14:26:05 ntpd[8457]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
 3 Mar 14:26:05 ntpd[8457]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 1.2.2.19:123
 3 Mar 14:26:05 ntpd[8457]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
```

I want to know when time is synchronized, and by how many seconds it changed on the local host when the sync was done.
I think I need to increase the log file verbosity, but I don't know how to do this. Pls help.
I couldn't find anything relevant in `/etc/ntp.conf`, even after reading `man 5 ntp.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need increased log verbosity.  What you need is to view (and probably graph) the statistics files in `/var/log/ntpstats/`, and/or monitor NTP through a monitoring system like collectd, nagios, prometheus, or telegraf.

Synchronisation is not a one-off event; it's something that happens constantly.  NTP makes constant minor adjustments to the *rate* of the clock, not its *value*.  So you shouldn't expect to see log messages saying `ntpd` has synced the clock; rather, in the stats files you'll see point-in-time samples of how *well* it is synced.

To see how well your local clock is doing, you'll want to look at `loopstats`.  I made a (very rough) [interactive graphing script](https://github.com/paulgear/ntpmon/blob/master/misc/loopstatsplot) to do that.  You can check out how well your peers are doing by looking at `peerstats`.  I made [a similar script](https://github.com/paulgear/ntpmon/blob/master/misc/peerstatsplot) to do that.  You can find out more about the stats files at http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/monopt.html

To monitor your system with one of the above-mentioned monitoring tools, check out [NTPmon](https://github.com/paulgear/ntpmon/), starting at the top level of that repo.

If you are concerned about your clock's accuracy, the most important thing you should do is include more sources in your configuration.  The [NTP Best Current Practices (RFC8633)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8633) [recommends a minimum of 4 sources](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8633#section-3.2), but using the `pool` directive and letting `ntpd` decide how many it needs is best.

(You probably also don't need `burst` in your `server` line - some NTP servers will block clients which use this; `iburst` is usually fine, though.)

Comment: Very big thanks for answer!  for monitoring we use prometheus, so i go configure node_exporter to see how ntp works.